# How to delete a system call in kernel？

Tags: linux, kernel, system-calls

As title, I would like to delete a system call entry e.g., open, I remove the line in `arch/x86/entry/syscalls/syscall_64.tb`. However the kernel image size does not change. What's the proper way to let the compiler not expand the system call macro and ignore all functions that are unused?

Comment: `However the kernel image size does not change.` - Adding/removing features from the code doesn't imply changing executable's size. `What's the proper way to let the compiler not expand the system call macro` - remove that call. Note, that *compiler* by itself is unaware about system calls list in `syscall_64.tb` file and its meaning. So it cannot filter out `SYSCALL_DEFINE` calls for names which are not listed in that file.

Comment: I understand that. It seems to me that I have to remove the implementation too.